# Send Email to customers automatically

Tags: sales-order, admin-panel, order-email, ee-2.2.5

I am facing issue in order update.

Presently when i create an order 
[image]

We have Email order confirmation checked by default.

But similarly for order update/ create invoice/ create shipment 
[image]

I need this to be checked by default as the orders may be updated/ shipment may be created from other source for my store.

Answer (score 1):

To make the "`Notify Customer by Email`" checkbox checked by default, you need to add `checked="checked"` in the phtml template.

You can override the template file in your custom module as follows:

**app/code/Anshu/Custom/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="left">
            <referenceBlock name="order_tab_info">
                <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\History" name="order_history" template="Anshu_Custom::order/view/history.phtml"/>
            </referenceBlock>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**app/code/Anshu/Custom/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/history.phtml**

```
<?php
// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile
?>
<div id="order_history_block" class="edit-order-comments">
    <?php if ($block->canAddComment()):?>
        <div class="order-history-block" id="history_form">

            <div class="admin__field">
                <label for="history_status" class="admin__field-label"><?= /* @noEscape */ __('Status') ?></label>
                <div class="admin__field-control">
                    <select name="history[status]" id="history_status" class="admin__control-select">
                        <?php foreach ($block->getStatuses() as $_code => $_label): ?>
                            <option value="<?= $block->escapeHtml($_code) ?>"<?php if ($_code == $block->getOrder()->getStatus()): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>><?= $block->escapeHtml($_label) ?></option>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="admin__field">
                <label for="history_comment" class="admin__field-label">
                    <?= /* @noEscape */ __('Comment') ?>
                </label>
                <div class="admin__field-control">
                    <textarea name="history[comment]"
                              rows="3"
                              cols="5"
                              id="history_comment"
                              class="admin__control-textarea"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="admin__field">
                <div class="order-history-comments-options">
                    <div class="admin__field admin__field-option">
                        <?php if ($block->canSendCommentEmail()): ?>
                            <input name="history[is_customer_notified]"
                                   type="checkbox"
                                   id="history_notify"
                                   class="admin__control-checkbox"
                                   checked="checked"
                                   value="1" />
                            <label class="admin__field-label" for="history_notify">
                                <?= /* @noEscape */ __('Notify Customer by Email') ?>
                            </label>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>

                    <div class="admin__field admin__field-option">
                        <input name="history[is_visible_on_front]"
                               type="checkbox"
                               id="history_visible"
                               class="admin__control-checkbox"
                               value="1" />
                        <label class="admin__field-label" for="history_visible">
                            <?= /* @noEscape */ __('Visible on Storefront') ?>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="order-history-comments-actions">
                    <?= $block->getChildHtml('submit_button') ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endif;?>

    <ul class="note-list">
        <?php foreach ($block->getOrder()->getStatusHistoryCollection(true) as $_item): ?>
            <li class="note-list-item">
                <span class="note-list-date"><?= /* @noEscape */ $block->formatDate($_item->getCreatedAt(), \IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM) ?></span>
                <span class="note-list-time"><?= /* @noEscape */ $block->formatTime($_item->getCreatedAt(), \IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM) ?></span>
                <span class="note-list-status"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getStatusLabel()) ?></span>
                <span class="note-list-customer">
                <?= /* @noEscape */ __('Customer') ?>
                    <?php if ($block->isCustomerNotificationNotApplicable($_item)): ?>
                        <span class="note-list-customer-notapplicable"><?= /* @noEscape */ __('Notification Not Applicable') ?></span>
                    <?php elseif ($_item->getIsCustomerNotified()): ?>
                        <span class="note-list-customer-notified"><?= /* @noEscape */ __('Notified') ?></span>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <span class="note-list-customer-not-notified"><?= /* @noEscape */ __('Not Notified') ?></span>
                    <?php endif; ?>
            </span>
                <?php if ($_item->getComment()): ?>
                    <div class="note-list-comment"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getComment(), ['b', 'br', 'strong', 'i', 'u', 'a']) ?></div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
    <script>
        require(['prototype'], function(){

            if($('order_status'))$('order_status').update('<?= $block->escapeJs($block->escapeHtml($block->getOrder()->getStatusLabel())) ?>');

        });
    </script>
</div>
```

Here `Anshu` is the namespace and `Custom` is the module name.

Answer (score 0):

I used the guidelines [here](https://medium.com/@teacha/magento-2-email-copy-of-shipment-checked-by-default-e7662117d983) and it worked. Note, it's important to make such customization in a child theme instead of magento core obviously.

Answer (score 0):

This answer was tested on `magento 2.4.3`

You can edit the default view in magento's core code:

`magento_root/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/emplates/order/view/history.phtml`

Add `checked="checked"` to this input:

```
<input name="history[is_customer_notified]"
                                   type="checkbox"
                                   id="history_notify"
                                   class="admin__control-checkbox"
                                   value="1"/>
                            <label class="admin__field-label" for="history_notify">
                                <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Notify Customer by Email')) ?>
                            </label>
```

Result:

```
<input name="history[is_customer_notified]"
                                   type="checkbox"
                                   id="history_notify"
                                   class="admin__control-checkbox"
                                   value="1" 
                                   checked="checked"/>
                            <label class="admin__field-label" for="history_notify">
                                <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Notify Customer by Email')) ?>
                            </label>
```